# cannot convert a dictionary's int-value to String in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a webService, which is returning some data. here is the link http://portal.pfs-ltd.org/LoginService1114?deviceid=89A04BDB-53AA-4441-9AFD-287729ACFE7F&imeino=12345678&SerialNo=f7pln20mfpfl&username=TST0002&password=TST0002&type=agent&status=Login&flag=True&Brand=Ipad&SimSerialNumber=&TelePhoneNumber=&Model=0&InstalledVersion=1.0
I'm unable to convert the value(int) for a key to a var of type String

```
var ApplicationVersion: String = dict["ApplicationVersion"] as String
```

Comment: `String(dict["ApplicationVersion"])` ?

Comment: not converting please follow the above link and then copy the whole data of webpage and paste it in the following link [link] (json.parser.online.fr) and in the first object u will see the above key and its value,

Answer (score 2):

`as` is for typecasting, not converting. You need to make a string from the integer value:

```
let version = dict["ApplicationVersion"] as Int
let applicationVersion = "\(version)"
```

Note that this performs no safety checking or validation.

Answer (score 2):

Your json is not a dictionary, but a nested array.

```
let json: [AnyObject] = ...
let dict = json[0][0] as NSDictionary
var applicationVersion = String(dict["ApplicationVersion"] as Int)
```

Comment: but dict is an identifier of type NSDictionary, right? and that dictionary contains values of int, string, bool that part is confusing, as i know that dictionary values can be only of one type.... ??

Comment: `NSDictionary` (different to a swift `Dictionary`) can hold values of many types, and a `Dictionary` defined as `[String:AnyObject]` can also hold multiple types.